# How to relate an object and feild in django?

Tags: python, django

Actually I didn't know how to ask this question. Say I have choices for subjects in my code with a subject code and subject name where I will use the `get_object_display` ORM to display the subject name.

```py
...
SUBJECTS = (('MA8151','Engineering Mathematics'),('PH8151','Physics-1'),...)
subject = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=SUBJECTS)
```

What I want is, I want to add another feature to the choice, that each choice has subject name, subject code and a credit point for it. I thought of creating a model

```py
...
subname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
subcode = models.CharField(max_length=6)
credit = models.SmallPositiveInteger()
```

But since I'm new to Django, I don't know how this will work on linking an object the name of a choice? On the whole, if I assign a `subcode` for a student, I want his records to be updated with relevant `subname` and relevant `credit` points.

Help me out reaching the solution. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could read about Djangos `ForeignKey` field, that seems to be what you need to link the 2 models together

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ForeignKey()` `ManyToManyField` `OneToOneField` you can refer https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#verbose-field-names